# Swift UITableView black background on native iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

Using: Xcode 7 Beta, Swift 2.0

I have a `UITableView`, in the Desktop simulator is all fine, but on my native iPhone 6+ the background on the empty rows is black

[image]

Setting a own background color to the TableView doesnt solve this problem. 
Does anyone has a idea?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I have the same problem. It's appears on an iphone 5 with ios 8.4 or a simulator with 8.1. Everything looks normal in a simulator with ios 9.

Comment: To reproduce, just create a new split view project and run it on 8.x and 9. The background is grey on 8.x.

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same issue in **XCode 11.2.1**. Tried to solve this in storyboard a lot. I have set the background color of the tableview and cells to white color. But evenif it is set in the storyboard, it still shows the default black color. After this I tried setting it programmatically and it worked!!

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: That is some strange behaviour.

Anyway, thanks and upvoted your answer...you saved me from getting frustrated.

Comment: I experienced the same issue in XCode 13.4.1. Table view looks fine in simulator but on an actual device the background is black and the text is white. Programmatically setting the cell background to white and cell label text to black solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed.. the background color was the problem.. i choose "White color" but it seems that he understand this as "Default" and this was a transparent color. I choose a light different white background color and now it works.. very strange

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered the same issue whilst trying to 'dim' a cell. Seems the cell by default is set to be non opaque hence no transparency. Setting the value to false did the trick.

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.isOpaque = false
```

Then all you need to do is set the tableviews background colour.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score -1):

What solved the problem for me is setting the table view's background color to white with 100% opacity manually.